# ria services server side data structure: is it shared between threads

Tags: c#, asp.net, silverlight, wcf-ria-services, ria

So suppose I have ria services DomainDataService class:

```
public partial class SomeService : LinqToEntitiesDomainService<SomeEntities>
{
    List<string> list = new List<string>();
    public IQueryable<SomeEntity> GetSomeEntity()
    {
       list.Add("test");
       ...
    }
}
```

There is a global variable `list`. `GetSomeEntity` method can obviously be called simultaneously. The question: is `list` shared between parallel `GetSomeEntity` invocation, i.e. do I have to protect it with locks?
I guess the same applies to all asp.net server side flavors, for instance web services (or not?).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should depend on the context mode for the service. You can control this via an attribute:

```
[EnableClientAccess()]
[ServiceBehavior(ConcurrencyMode = ConcurrencyMode.Multiple)]
public partial class SomeService : LinqToEntitiesDomainService<SomeEntities>
{
```

I believe the default option is `ConcurrencyMode.Single`.

From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.servicebehaviorattribute.concurrencymode.aspx): "Setting ConcurrencyMode to Single instructs the system to restrict instances of the service to one thread of execution at a time, which frees you from dealing with threading issues"

So, to answer your question, the global `list` is not shared between calls to your service (unless you make is static).